# to manage seasonal prices for hotel rooms

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to manage seasonal prices for hotel rooms.

In my Price table :

```
season        startdate     enddate      price   room_id
----------- ------------- --------------------------------


offseason     2014-03-01   2014-07-30    6500        1



   season     2014-08-01   2014-12-28    7500        1



peakseason    2015-01-01   2015-03-30    8500        1
```

startdate and enddate are set as date and room_id is the id from room table .

If a person choose room_id 1 with checkin date 15-03-2014 & checkout date : 17-03-2014 .

I want to calculate the above check in and check out date  are included in  which season ?

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: did you try anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
SELECT season from price_table where str_to_date(startdate,'%d-%m-%Y')>='15-03-2014' and str_to_date(enddate,'%d-%m-%Y')<='17-03-2014' and room_id=1
```

Comment: when we use str_to_date(startdate,'%dd-%m-%Y')='15-03-2014' '=' function gives only the corresponding value. In my table 2014-03-01  to 2014-07-30 off season, if a person select a checkindate =05-03-2014 and checkoutdate=07-03-2014, how can i calculate season ???